# LTSpice "Could not open library file" after moving .CIR file associated with symbol

Tags: ltspice

I've imported a third party spice model into LTSpice using this guide: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

My simulation works great, but now if I move the new symbol's associated ".CIR" file to anywhere else on my computer I run into "could not open library file [path]" which is still pointing to my downloads folder where it originally was when I created the symbol.

I tried editing the .asy file and the SYMATTR ModelFile but it does not seem to change anything.

[image]

Comment: `SYMATTR ModelFile` should not be blank if you indeed followed the article's directions.  I think it's suspect your cursor is there and the title bar for Notepad has an asterisk indicating you modified the file before grabbing a screenshot.  Please describe what you changed between following the article's directions and taking your screenshot.

Comment: My apologies. I changed SYMATTR ModelFile to the new path but I still receive the same error. Regardless of what I change it to, LTSpice will only to point to the location the .CIR file originally was when the symbol was autogenerated.

Comment: Oh ok.  In that case I suggest first moving the library file (.CIR, .LIB, or dot-whatever) to `Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub` and then repeating the procedure in the article.  Doing that should make the auto-generated symbol able to be used universally throughout your computer.  Also, if you want to edit symbol attributes, it's better to open the symbol (.ASY file) in LTspice and simply do a CTRL+A to bring up the symbol attributes window.

Comment: @Ste Kulov Worked. Thanks!